# loop through json reactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

Id like to loop through a json file displaying the first level values as links as so:

```
  <Route path='/acordes' component={Acordes}>
    <IndexRoute component={La} />
    <Route path='laSib' component={LaSib} />
    <Route path='query' component={Query} />
  </Route>
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "la": {
        "tonoMayor": "A",
        "tonoMenor": "Am",
        "septima": "A7",
        "sexta": "A6",
        "menorSexta": "Am6",
        "menorSeptima": "Am7",
        "septimaMayor": "A7M",
        "disminuida": "Adim7",
        "aumentados": "Aaug"
    },
    "la#Sib": {
        "tonoMayor": "la#",
        "tonoMenor": "A#m",
        "septima": "A#m",
        "sexta": "A#6",
        "menorSexta": "A#m6",
        "menorSeptima": "A#m7",
        "septimaMayor": "A#7m",
        "disminuida": "A#dim7",
        "aumentados": "A#aug"
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory, DefaultRoute, IndexLink } from 'react-router'
import Data from '!json!../json/acordes.json';

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Container}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path='/acordes' component={Acordes}>
            <IndexRoute component={La} />
            <Route path='laSib' component={LaSib} />
            <Route path='query' component={Query} />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/about(/:name)' component={About} />
          <Route path='/namedComponent' component={NamedComponents}>
            <IndexRoute components={{ title: Title, subTitle: SubTitle }} />
          </Route>
          <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Then when the user clicks on {la} it should show the contents of it from the json.